# Testing uniform convergence over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I need to test whether the sequence of functions $f_n$ given by $f_{n}(x)= n^2(e^{x/n} -1 -x/n)$ converges uniformly over $\mathbb{R}$ or not.

I know this sequence converges pointwise to $x^2/2$.

Now I consider $M_n = \text{sup}_
{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|n^2(e^{x/n} -1 -x/n)- x^2/2\right|$

$M_n \ge \left|n^2(e^{n/n} -1 -n/n)- n^2/2\right|$

as $n \to \infty$ ,$M_n \to \infty$ , so this is not uniformly convergent.

Is this proof correct and rigorous enough ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your proof looks good.

Comment: Yeah Clement Yung is right, the proof looks good.

Comment: Thank you, for the quick response.